# Why Microsoft Remote Desktop cannot make full use of network bandwidth?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

I am using Microsoft RDP on my OS X in order to control the Windows PC inside my local network. The two computers are connected via a 1Gbps Ethernet router, so the bandwidth shouldn't be a bottleneck. However, I find that the frame rate of RDP is not so satisfactory. Both the frame rate and image quality are very low when watching videos or running graphical programs. According to inspections, I found that the RDP is only using a few MB/s of the bandwidth which is far from full. So why it cannot make full use of the network bandwidth and provide promising quality and frame rate so that I can control it through the LAN as I were directly using it?

Comment: This is an honest and interesting question by OP. What performance could you expect? What is the limitation? What does the MS documentation say about this?

Comment: You can't force an application to use more bandwidth then it needs.  If you are upset about the quality of the image, then you will have to use a program, that has the options to send a better picture.  `Microsoft RDP` is a great built-in tool if you can accept it has limitations.  Besides, [Microsoft Remote Desktop Bandwidth Usage](http://superuser.com/questions/43797/microsoft-remote-desktop-bandwidth-usage?rq=1), indicates your measurements are not measuring the correct thing anyways.

Comment: Bandwidth is not your limitation.  Look into [RemoteFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RemoteFX) for more info.

Comment: Although remote desktop is pretty good, it feels like it hasn't been updated in the last 5-10years. And only it's visuals have had any love.