# What is the difference in loading a website in windows RDP and browser?

Tags: remote-desktop

I want to run a web application 24/7. I can do that in Windows RDP server from Alibaba cloud but the application requires it to be visible at all time. Will it save some bandwidth if open that RDP server on my laptop or should I run that web app on my laptop?

What will be the major differences in both of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your browser with RDP will consume more bandwidth. Here are some details on how much: [Microsoft Remote Desktop Bandwidth Usage](https://superuser.com/questions/43797/microsoft-remote-desktop-bandwidth-usage)

There is no functional difference between which browser you use. Just make sure you configure your web app to accept non-localhost connections.

In short: RDP will use more bandwidth than HTTP.